# Hive query - divide value by the amount of values in the group

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to create a query in which I divide one of the values in the amount of results from that group, but I couldn't find an answer regarding how to perform it.

Let's say my data is as follows:

| request_id | client_name | request_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | bob | 10 |
| a | alice | 10 |
| b | bob | 20 |
| b | charlie | 20 |

I would like to get a query that'll return a single result for each set of client_name & request, but having the request_price be the request_price / amount of clients per request. something in the likes of -

`select request_id, client_name, AVG(request_price) / <SIZE_OF_GROUP> from DATA group by request_id`

and the result should be -

| request_id | client_name | calculated_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | bob | 5 |
| a | alice | 5 |
| b | bob | 10 |
| b | charlie | 10 |

Can anyone assist? Is there a way to do it in a single query?

Comment: Could you provide a better example with the expected output?

Comment: sure! fo this example i would want to get 2 rows: 1. "a", "bob", 5. 2. "a", "alice", 5    @mck

Comment: What about when there are multiple rows for each client? Could you give an example of that?

Comment: @mck edited the question with examples

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the average over a window partitioned by `request_id`:

```
select
    request_id,
    client_name,
    AVG(request_price) over (partition by request_id) / COUNT(request_price) over (partition by request_id) as calculated_value
from DATA
```

Comment: this won't give me what i'm looking for - it will just calculate the average of request_price, and not the averge divided by the amount of rows

Comment: @Yehuda sorry, could you check the edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can first calculate the grouped values of request_id then join the data with main table

Please refer below:

```
  hive> select * from data
    > ;
OK
a   bob 10
a   alice   10
b   bob 20
b   charlie 20
Time taken: 0.082 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)

select data.req_id,data.client_name,req_price/cnt as calc_val from data join (select req_id,count(req_id) as cnt from data group by req_id) tmp
on data.req_id=tmp.req_id;

Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 580 msec
OK
a   bob 5.0
a   alice   5.0
b   bob 10.0
b   charlie 10.0
Time taken: 46.804 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

There may be other ways to achieve same thing but this is what i could think of

Comment: thanks. this works, but i'm afraid about the performance cost of it vs. the cost of running a window function (as the solution suggested).

Comment: You can both queries and check the stats you can stick where performance is better. Please share the stats also in comment for both cases